# save_post trigerred twice

Tags: php, hooks, save-post

I am trying to add more functionality to the update button. My end result is that I wish to call a python script but for now I am messing around with writing a log file. This is resulting in the log file being written to twice. Can someone help me?

```
 add_action('save_post', 'test',10,2);

function test($id, $post) 
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'item'){
        return;
    }

     if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    if (wp_is_post_revision($id)) {
        return;
    }

    if (wp_is_post_autosave($id)) {
        return;
    }

    $tmp = fopen(dirname(__file__).'/my_logs.txt', "a+"); 
    fwrite($tmp,"\n".$id." - Fail\n");
    fclose($tmp);     
           

}
```

I added the following:

```
 if(did_action($save_post)==0){
    $tmp = fopen(dirname(__file__).'/my_logs.txt', "a+"); 
    fwrite($tmp,"\n".did_action($save_post)." - Fail\n");
    fclose($tmp);     
}
```

but still I am getting:

```
0 - Fail

0 - Fail
```

Comment: There is a nice function you can use to prevent this, [did_action( string $hook_name )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/did_action/), this returns the number of times the event was called so you can use that to prevent multiple executions. If that doesn't help you maybe have a update post action that has the same callback

Comment: Can you kindly check my edited question?

Comment: Does `$save_post` contain the hook name, `save_post`?

Comment: Are you using gutenberg?

Comment: You'd need to pass the hook name (`save_post`) to `did_action`, not a variable as you are doing.